# 'scanner' is never closed

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm currently working on a project in Eclipse and I'm getting a resource leak: 'scanner' never closed. I assumed I was fine without it but I suppose not. Any advice?

```
package mypackage;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class TreeSetUse {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String str;
        TreeSet<String> treeSet = new TreeSet<>();
        System.out.println("Enter line: ");
        str = scanner.nextLine();
        
        for(String word: str.split(" ")){
            treeSet.add(word);
        }

        Iterator<String> iterator = treeSet.iterator();

        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(iterator.next());
        }

    }
   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Scanner` implements the `AutoCloseable` interface. That means that as long as you use it as a resource inside a `try-with-resources` block it is guaranteed to be closed when the block exits irrespective of how the block exits:

```
try(Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
    ...
}
```

I recommend you always use this idiom when using a class that implements `AutoCloseable`.

Comment: Usually yes, but this is the rare case where you should *not* close the `Scanner`. The reason is that closing the `Scanner` will close the backing resource, in this case `System.in`. Once you close that the entire JVM will no longer be able to read anything from standard input anymore. So while you should usually close `Scanner` instances like you suggest, you should ignore the warning when the `Scanner` is wrapping `System.in`. That can be done using `@SuppressWarnings("resource")`, but the scope often needs to be larger than you'd actually want (the method, not just the variable).

Comment: @RobSpoor good point. Would it be safe if the try block is the whole `main` body? Closing `in` when the application is exiting wouldn't be an issue I assume?

Comment: If the entire application is in a try-with-resources block it's usually safe, because then when the try-with-resources block ends, so does the application, and there's nothing to read from `System.in` anymore. Now I said "usually" because there could be non-daemon threads that try to read from `System.in`, and those may remain active once the main thread ends. However, that's a bad idea anyway; multi-threaded access to `System.in` is a terrible idea.